# Pure Data comport output

Tags: arduino, puredata

I have made an electronic drum-kit in Pure Data. By using an Arduino I am able to send data from the Arduino to Pure Data through the comport object. I am making a control panel in Pure Data and was looking for a way to show that  Pure Data is connected to the Arduino. Right now I can only see it in the opening screen of Pure Data, but I would prefer that there is something visible shown inside the patch, if it is connected or closed. Is there a way to do this or do I just have to settle with it only being shown in the startup screen of Pure Data?

Answer (score 2):

It's tough to answer this without more information, but here is something that might work for you:

```
[comport]
 |     |
      [route open]
       |
      [toggle]
```

Toggle will be read 1 [X] if the port is open, and 0 [ ] if it's closed or lost, but there will be a slight delay.

It would be helpful to know more about your patch, especially how you are pulling data via comport.  It seems that you'd like a connection indicator because you are having connectivity issues, and if that is the case, you should definitely address that issue first.